# Give values to a sentence from a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, if-statement

I have 2 inpouts, several tweets in a list `['tweet 1', 'tweet 2',...]`  and a dictionary with `{'word1': value1;'word 2': value2;...}`.

Imagine the first tweet is like:

> 'I love eating potatoes'

And from the 500 words in the dictionary there is a value for

> {...;'love': 3;...;'potatoes': -1;...}.

The question is: how can I search in every row if there is/are a value/s for the sentence and give it a final score?

```
tweet=[]
values={}
    for list in tweet:
        divided_tweet=list.split()
```

I guess I have to start with this

Thank you all for the help

updated:

Hello everyone,
each answer worked, but not in the way I wanted.

I need to get a print out like:

```
print(str(tweet)+"// The total score is: "str(score))
```

So how can I define score?

Thank you very much

Comment: should it return 0 for a word if it doesn’t not exist?

Comment: is that really `'potatoes': -1`? or `'potatoes': 1`

Comment: `sum(dictionary.get(word, 0) for word in divided_tweet)`. Note: do not use python's builtin in types or functions as variable names, e.g. `list`.

Comment: @SwadhikarC yes, there are some positives and negatives values

Comment: @aws_apprentice yes it should

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a nested *list comprehension* to iterate over each string in the list of tweets, add their scores if they are present in the dictionary (this returns a list of scores)

```
[sum(d.get(j, 0) for j in i.split()) for i in t]
```

Or as @yuvgin suggests, you could create a dictionary with tweets as keys and their corresponding scores:

```
{i : sum(d.get(j, 0) for j in i.split()) for i in t}
```

**Example**

```
t = ['I love eating potatoes', 'second tweet']
d = {'love': 3,'potatoes': -1}
{i : sum(d.get(j, 0) for j in i.split()) for i in t}
# {'I love eating potatoes': 2, 'second tweet': 0}
```

Comment: I'd consider changing your solution to output a dictionary with corresponding tweets and scores. Would be easier to use... A dict comprehension obviously comes to mind..

Comment: So you'd add the scores to a dictionary where the keys are the actual tweets?

Comment: Yes, it seems like a more logical way to keep track of the score of each tweet than a list..

Comment: Yess nice suggestion added it to the answer

Comment: I updated the question, if you are so kind to help :)

Comment: @criser94 use `[print(f'{i}// The total score is: {sum(d.get(j, 0) for j in i.split())}') for i in t]`

Comment: don’t use list comprehension for printing

Comment: @aws_apprentice is right, a normal for loop is more optimal when not generating a list. So you should ideally replace my code with a normal for loop

Answer (score 1):

### If I understand your problem correctly, then below solution:

```
stream = ['I love tweet 1', 'I loves kt',] # Your input steam if tweets

kv = {'love': 1,'tweet': 2} # Your key value matching pair

print ([x for x in stream if any(j in kv for j in x.split())]) # o/p prints only those stream where atleast a single match is present in stream kv.

# output: ['I love tweet 1']
```